# How to cache video/audio while streaming in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, offline

In my app i have feature to cache media (image/audio/video) files. So when i was searching to achieve this i could easily find out open source libraries to cache images in iOS but i am not able to find anything to cache video/audio. Is it possible to cache video/audio while it is streaming. if so what is the right approach to achieve this? if not then what is the alternate solution to watch the video/audio in offline mode?

I am looking forward your response if anybody knows this please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022396/caching-videos-in-ios